# How to remove double empty lines in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, special-characters, newline, powerpoint

I am exporting data from MS Access to MS PowerPoint, and a part of the data is text fields (long) with multiple paragraphs, as in hitting `ENTER` between the lines in a single field.
This results, after the export in a variety of phenomena which I'd like to clear. One of the most disturbing is control and special characters appearing in the Powerpoint slides.

I mainly tries using :search and replace" methods like

> shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text,
>   "this", "that")

but I have no idea how to solve the double blank line issues. Moreover, there seems to be an entire set of newline characters and combinations (see [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)), and I have no idea which ones are there.
In MS Word it's relatively easier, since its search and replace functionality supports these special characters. Not so in Powerpoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this macro to remove multiple blank lines

```
Function removeMultiBlank(s As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^\s"

        removeMultiBlank= .Replace(s, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Use it like

```
With shp.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = removeMultiBlank(.Text)
End With
```

Comment: @Jbjstam Yes, it will. OP shouldn't use it on formatted text. Useful for text imported from Access.