# wget working in terminal but not working from shell script

Tags: shell, wget

I have a simple shell script which is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wget -O glove.840B.300d.zip http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip
```

When I run it using sh command, I get the following error.

```
--2017-06-29 20:35:41--  http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip%0D
Resolving nlp.stanford.edu (nlp.stanford.edu)... 171.64.67.140
Connecting to nlp.stanford.edu (nlp.stanford.edu)|171.64.67.140|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip%0d [following]
--2017-06-29 20:35:41--  https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip%0d
Connecting to nlp.stanford.edu (nlp.stanford.edu)|171.64.67.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-06-29 20:35:41 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

But when I run the same `wget` command (written in the shell script) from terminal, it works fine! What is the problem in my shell script? What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the %0d in the end. It seems like somewhere along the way, you used DOS/Windows line endings in a Linux environment. that %0d is a "carriage return" character, since in Windows CR LF (carriage return line feed) is used for newlines. Unix expects just LF and includes the extra character in the command line.

See [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Answer (score 0):

You have edited your script using something which uses DOS line-endings.  So `wget` is seeing a spurious carriage-return (hex 0D) at the end of the line.

Replace the DOS line-endings (CR-LF) with Unix ones (LF) and all will be well.