# Error running script inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a simple command inside a file.sh script, but is not working.

My Dockerfile is like this

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
COPY SqlCmdStartup.sh SqlCmdStartup.sh
COPY SqlCmdScript.sql SqlCmdScript.sql
RUN chmod +x ./SqlCmdStartup.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

The first line of SqlCmdStartup.sh is

```
sleep 20s
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
sleep: invalid time interval '20s\r'
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
```

I'm following this example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt784660.aspx

Comment: What about my response ? did it work ?

Answer (score 2):

The `\r` in the error message suggests that your line endings are badly encoded.

Ensure that end of line chars of `SqlCmdStartup.sh` are LF for Unix not CR LF (Windows) as it seem to be.

More details here : [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)