# Is it possible to add format to table cells in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to add line breaks to a Microsoft Access cell? If I want to save some text like this:

```
"text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text 
      text text text text text text"
```

Would it be possible? Or can it only be saved as one line?

Comment: it is not clear what you mean. Are you entering the text manually, programmatically (VBA) or using SQL? What do you mean by `cell`? A `TextBox` a table column, something else?

Comment: Add a line break to sql table during design view.

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add line breaks in Microsoft Access.

To add a line break in a text box, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To add a line break using SQL, add the `Chr` function:

```
INSERT Into MyTable(MyTextField)
SELECT "text text text text text text text" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & 
"text text text text text text text"  & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & 
"      text text text text text text"
```

`Chr(10)` is the line feed character. `Chr(13)` is the carriage return character. Generally, in Windows, you make a new line by using a character return and a line feed (like you would in a type machine), but some operating systems use one (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552775/7296893) for more details).