# Why it gives me linebreaks errors?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I run VSC, I use the configuration file for airbnb for ESlint.

And when I wanted to test it, I tried this:

```
const a = 'a';
const b = `${a}Hi`;
const d = function () {
  return b;
};
d();
```

The problem is that it keeps giving me errors about linebreaks:

```
Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'. (linebreak-style)
```

There are 6 type of this error, plus this:

```
Unexpected unnamed function. (func-names)
```

It's getting annoying and I'm guessing it is because of the guide used, right?

Comment: you can change them from the bottom right corner if needed

Comment: Oh finally. I never seen that. But can you please explain what was that? What does linebreak/carnage return mean(LF,CRLF)? Also the last error "Unexpected unamed function" didn't get solved.

Comment: Regarding your second error, see: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names

Comment: What those linebreaks mean, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up:
The difference between linebreaks is analysed here: [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

In order to change between CRLF and LF in Visual Studio Code you click on the bottom right side where the selected option is displayed.

For the func-names reference: [func-names](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names)