# What is the difference between "\n" (newline) and "\r" (carriage return) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, newline, whitespace, linefeed

```
y = "Ruby\riscool"
x = "Ruby\niscool"

if x == y
  puts x
  puts y
else
  print 'Not equal!'
end
```

The newline and carriage return character both give the same output. However, the code above is false, and triggers the else statement. I don't understand how I can get the same output, but for both to be unequal? Can someone give and example and explain the difference between the two whitespace characters? Thanks!

Comment: "both give the same output." - no, [they don't](https://pastebin.com/8faQ6fQG).

Comment: Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r?answertab=active#tab-top) i think its the same in ruby

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).

Comment: In most terminals `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line without advancing lines, so you can re-write text. `\n` moves to the beginning *and* advances the line.

Comment: Just for clarification, is there a difference between the two if I use them in a script and not in a shell? Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Practical1: depends on where you'll run that script. In most cases yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

\n and \r doesn't make a lot difference in output both are used to print a new line though they perform same action they are different it can be observed in case of input for example if we are getting a matrix as input like:

1 2 3 (\n)

4 5 6 (\n)

7 8 9 (\r)

to give new line as input we will use \n(enter) when the input end carriage return come to play which is (\r).