# In PHP in Windows, do 'linefeed (LF)' and 'carriage return (CR)' mean the same thing?

Tags: php, escaping, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm using **PHP 7.2.10**

I'm using **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I tried following two codes but I received the same output in both the cases :

**Code 1 :**

```
<?php

echo "stackoverflow\nnine" ;

?>
```

**Code 2 :**

```
<?php

echo "stackoverflow\rnine" ;

?>
```

Same output for both of the above programs :

```
stackoverflow
nine
```

As per my knowledge, **Linefeed**(`\n`) means to advance downward to the next line and **Carriage return**(`\r`) means to return to the beginning of the current line without advancing downward.

Then, why I am getting the same output for the things which are entirely different in nature and in meaning?

Why I'm getting the output with **carriage return**(`\r`) on the next line advanced downward?

Comment: It's not PHP that determines what it does, it's the system.

Comment: They both do the same thing in practice (they *might* do something different if you've got an electronic typewriter) - `LF` is ACII 10 and `CR` ASCII 13; Unix used LF to end the line, old versions of Mac used CR - while Windows and MIME tend to use both as `CRLF` - [possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Comment: try running this code in a terminal, you will see the difference ;)

Comment: we also have a beautiful constant PHP_EOL which will make lineendings works on whatever OS PHP runs on