# How do I differentiate between different whitespace characters in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, whitespace

I can show whitespace ("invisibles") in Xcode 10, and some of the resulting placeholder glyphs are easy to figure out, but I cannot figure out all of them.

For instance, which line ending is this supposed to represent: `¤`?

Is there a list of all of them, or is there a convention for representing whitespace characters with other glyphs that I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `¤` character represents a CR (carriage return) line ending. Windows files typically use CRLF (carriage return & line feed) line endings, which are represented with `¤┐`. Old versions of macOS only used CR as a line ending. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552775/3151675))

Full list:

```
╔════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Symbol ║                     Meaning                      ║
╠════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ·      ║ space                                            ║
║ ···•   ║ tabulator (when Indent Using is set to "Spaces") ║
║ »      ║ tabulator (when Indent Using is set to "Tabs")   ║
║ ¤      ║ CR line ending                                   ║
║ ┐      ║ LF line ending                                   ║
║ ¤┐     ║ CRLF line ending                                 ║
╚════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```