# What does this LF and CRLF warning message from Git mean?

Tags: git, react-native

I encountered the following message while using Git with react-native: `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.js. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory`

What does LF and CRLF mean in this warning, and what does the warning mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LF` is line feed and `CRLF` is Carriage Return - Line Feed. They both refer to the ASCII code(s) of how the new lines in your files are stored. As a programmer, you might have run into the problem that sometimes you need to do `\n` (LF) and other times you have to do `\r\n` (CRLF) to get a new line to output.

Git is telling you that when it commits the file changes, it will store the new lines as the DOS-style (CRLF) instead of the Unix-style (LF).