# Why is this code failing in a 32-bit enviroment?

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, circular-reference

I'm moving a very simple django app from my desktop pc to a virtualbox server.
I have copied the hole proyect, except for the virtualenv sources folder. 
Then, i've created a virtualenv and installed dependencies in the same way. When i run manage.py a circular reference error cames in claming `The included URLconf 'pmkwebPdf.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it`

This is the project dir:

```
PmkwebPdf
    media
    pmkwebPdf
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    src
        migrations
            ...
        processor
            ...
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    templates
        ...
    venv
        ...
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

It's certanly an error with the **urlpatterns**.
**So i did this.**

*pmkWebPdf.urls*

```
from django.contrib import admin
#from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', include('src.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In this file, if i remove the `path('', include('src.urls')),` and its dependecies **the error is gone**.

*src/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

from pmkwebPdf import settings
#from src.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', index, name='index')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After leaving the *pmkWebPdf.urls* without the lines commented, i discovered that, in this file, **if i leave the urlpatters empty and remove the `from src.views import index` line. The server runs.**

I've created the same proyect in both my desktop pc and my virtual machine **following the same procedure** and **the result is different**.

There are **differences** between the env
The **virtual machine** must run on **32-bit**. So the difference is that it runs **python 3.5.2 vs 3.6.8** (the version of python in my desktop 64-bit pc).
**However, venv dependencies are exactly the same.**

This is traceback of the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/hernan/pmk/pmkwebPdf/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'pmkwebPdf.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

### Any ideas on what may be causing this or why is it happening?

Comment: Did you name a file `urlpatterns.py`, or name a folder `urlpatterns`? If you did, pick a different name.

Comment: Also, have you checked your code for circular imports? We certainly don't have enough information to check it from here.

Comment: No folder named urlpatterns. But, if it's a circular import, why would i get this error in the first enviroment and not in the second? It's the same code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on control characters.

The first enviroment got **CR** and the second **LF**.

More info about the meaning and difference between this two can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552775/2796613).