# Which one of LF and CRLF should I use in a django project?

Tags: python, django, newline

I am collaborating on a course-django project with other several students, and I found line separator mixed up, some files use LF, and other files use CRLF. I feel confused, although now everything is well, no one knows future. so which one we should set in project level? do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you're on an typewriter you should use CR+LF. Otherwise LF will suffice. :)

CR+LF is basically just using up two characters instead of one.

[Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)