# C undefined behaviour with fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, newline, undefined-behavior

I have a code snippet below.
On macOS, I have run it in Xcode and CLion with the same odd result.
On the other hand, on Linux when compiled with gcc it runs flawlessly.
I would like to know whether the code at any point produces undefined behaviour.
The input file it tries to parse is the vigenére table, you know, 26-character rows with the latin alphabet, and the letters are shifted left by 1 on the 1 lower row.
Every line is terminated by CRLF.
The expected output is the table printed out on the console.
The unexpected part is that az least 1 line is displayed incorrectyl on macOS.
Here’s the input btw:
https://pastebin.com/QnucTAFs
(I dont know however, whether the corresponding line endings got preserved)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** parse(char *path) {
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
    char **table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 26);
    int i = -1;

    do table[++i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 27);
    while (fscanf(f, "%s", table[i]) > 0);

    return table;
}

int main() {
    char **table = parse("Vtabla.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
            printf("%c", table[i][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good to `fclose(f);` in the `parse` function, and it looks like this will blow up if there are more lines in the file than you expect.

Comment: this code was never compiled

Comment: @SteveFriedl There cant be more lines, since the alphabet is 26-character long, that is the number of rows in the Vigenère table.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer - So if this program gets a malformed `Vtabla.dat` file, it's ok for it to segmentation fault?

Comment: "There can't be" are famous last words. In C, you must *make sure* there are not.

Comment: @P__J__ only the include statements are missing

Comment: @P__J__ but I have fixed it just in case

Comment: @PatrikNusszer you also have a typo in fscanf, `tabla[i]`.

Comment: Just like `#include` files. If they are not shown, they were not present in the code.

Comment: @anastaciu sorry, i Have copied out this snippet, and I started translating from Hungarian to English

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem. The best way is to *copy/paste* the *exact* code you have compiled, as I am sure you must know by now.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok

Comment: I did throw in my pennyworth: always check your limits. Never assume that input will be as you expect it to be.

Comment: Things that will make this program fail: 1) missing input file; 2) input file has too many input elements; 3) input file has too few input elements.

Comment: @WestherVane it now runs well.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I have posed the input to pastebin. It has not got any more than 26 lines, and it indeed opens if you give appropriate file path.

Comment: Your software will fail badly if *anything* goes wrong, and this is a *super* dangerous habit to get into.  You've gotten advice here to check your inputs, but you seem uninterested.  Good luck.

Comment: @stevefriedl oh so I am the one who is uninteresed? I have an input file with fixed row and column count, I have run the code a dozen times and have never seen it segfault. One of the rows I read always seem to be wrong, but it always vary on every run.

Comment: Given the file content you've shown and the code, it doesn't seem to invoke undefined behavior, the only potencial problem is the CRLF. the compiler might not be able to parse this correctly, this is a windows style line ending. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39259747/6865932.

Comment: That said, of course your code should have the propper error treatment for things like `malloc` and `fopen`.

Comment: @anastaciu thanks for that post. yes the line ending is crlf. actually, I could not parse it using fgets, but for that function it was clear for me that the problem is the line ending and did not know the same might got for fscanf. but actually, it worked on linux

Comment: "could not parse it using fgets" --> `char buf[80]; if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)) { buf[strcspn(buf, "\n\r")] = 0; assert(strlen(buf) == 26);  strcpy(table[i], buffer); }`.

Comment: If it's available, you might want to consider [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) it allows you to define the delimiters. @chux-ReinstateMonica's comment also seems like a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in this code, in this loop:

```
do table[++i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 27);
while (fscanf(f, "%s", table[i]) > 0);
```

The `table` holds 26 pointers, but on the iteration that `fscanf()` fails, the `table` variable's 27th pointer gets initialized via `malloc` in the previous step.  This corrupts the data in `table` on my system.  You can convince yourself of this by bumping the 26 in this line to 27 and see if your problems disappear:

```
char **table = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 26);
```

My rework of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LETTERS 26

char **parse(char *path) {
    char **table = calloc(LETTERS, sizeof(char *));

    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++) {
        table[i] = (char *) calloc(LETTERS+1, sizeof(char));

        if (fscanf(f, "%s", table[i]) <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return table;
}

int main() {
    char **table = parse("Vtabla.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LETTERS; j++)
            printf("%c", table[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
        free(table[i]);
    }

    free(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't think that 27 will ever be larger than 26" :-)

Comment: Yes, well spotted, that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion in the comments have been lively, but the OP seems interested in a narrower concern that many experienced developers are, so I'll post an answer that's not strictly on point to the question, but demonstrates the wider concerns.

I believe many of us have skipped error checking for conditions that we consider highly unlikely, but "file not found" or "file is malformed" are not even close to that category.  This attempts to address that, plus it closes the file after reading, plus it replaces a magic number ("26") with a constant.

While reading each input line, this will overflow the buffer if there happen to be too many characters, but I will leave this limit-check as an exercise to the reader.

Malformed user input is *so common* that it's imperative that one check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE  26

char ** parse(const char *path) {

    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

    if (f == 0)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot open input file %s (err=%s)", path, strerror(errno));

    char **table = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ALPHABET_SIZE);
    int i = -1;

    do
    {
      // BUG: overflows the table - see cdlane's answer
      table[++i] = malloc(ALPHABET_SIZE + 1);

                         // TODO: what if line is too long? Or too short?
    } while (i < ALPHABET_SIZE  &&  fscanf(f, "%s", table[i]) > 0);

    if (i != ALPHABET_SIZE)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Not enough input lines");

    fclose(f);

    return table;
}

int main() {
    char **table = parse("Vtabla.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < ALPHABET_SIZE; x++)
            printf("%c", table[i][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `fscanf(f, "%s", table[i])` --> `fscanf(f, "%26s", table[i])` else code is like [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have such a pathalogical dislike for `*scanf` that I couldn't bring myself to go there; your approach w/ `fgets()` was better.

Comment: UV for pathalogical dislike for *scanf.