# COPY INTO from Azure Dala lake gen2 to Azure Synapse does nothing

Tags: python, pandas, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy from azure data lake gen2 to table in azure synapse warehouse using local ssms. The `COPY INTO` statement is neither throwing any errors and nor dumping the data. I am copying the pandas df from centos server to azure data lake gen2 using `sep=',', encoding='utf-8'`. Here is the COPY statement that I am using.

```
COPY INTO dbo.SALES_CUTOMER_D 
FROM 'https://acoount_name/test-file-system/SALES_CUSTOMER_D_0.csv'
WITH (
 FILE_TYPE = 'csv',
 CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Storage Account Key', SECRET=''),
 FIELDQUOTE = '"',
 FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
 ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n',
 ENCODING = 'UTF8',
 FIRSTROW = 2
)
```

Comment: Try ERRORFILE option to see if it prints any errors to ERRORFILE. Remove the `FIELDQUOTE`, `FIELDTERMINATOR`, `ROWTERMINATOR`, you're using default values. It could have an effect. Beyond that you'll have to put the contents of the csv file and DDL for `SALES_CUTOMER_D` if you want someone to help you more. Also a good idea to specify the list of columns (`COPY INTO dbo.SALES_CUTOMER_D (col1, col2, ...) FROM ...`).

Comment: @Kashyap yes i tried it for sample csv called employee.csv wirh 10 rows with schema id int and name varchar 100 even for taht also same thing is happening

Comment: also when am trying to write errors to error file again it is throwing the error that access is denied error code 5

Comment: For ERROR FILE, provide full URL and for ERROR FILE CREDENTIAL use sas token not account key. Also run unix2dos on this input CSV file and try.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file has Unix-style line endings (LF) instead of Windows-style (CRLF).

See [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types) if you're not clear on CRLF.

Easiest way I know of checking is to open file in vi in binary mode with `set list`:

`vi -b -c 'set list' <file>`

To verify if this is the problem or not, you can do one of the following:

1. Tell COPY what line endings are in your file:

   ```
    COPY INTO dbo.SALES_CUTOMER_D 
    FROM 'https://acoount_name/test-file-system/SALES_CUSTOMER_D_0.csv'
    WITH (
       FILE_TYPE = 'csv',
       CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Storage Account Key', SECRET=''),
       ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A',
       FIRSTROW = 2
    )
   ```
2. Confirm that it's actually reading the file by making it parse the header. Remove `FIRSTROW = 2`.
3. Change line-endings:

- `unix2dos <csv file>`
- upload to datalake and try `COPY` again, without `ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n',` (that's the default value).

---

[A little gotcha](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest):

> COPY treats ‘\n’ as ‘\r\n’ internally. For more information, see the ROWTERMINATOR section.

In other words:

- If we don’t specify `ROWTERMINATOR` option or specify `ROWTERMINATOR=’\n’` or `ROWTERMINATOR=’0x0D0A’`, then the engine uses `\r\n` as terminator (Windows style).
- If we specify `ROWTERMINATOR=’0x0A’` then engine uses ‘\n’ as the terminator (Unix style)