# What is CRLF and LF? What's the use case in Git?

Tags: newline, core.autocrlf, crlf-vulnerability

I am new exploring git commands and suddenly found LF and CRLF. When run the command git add  the terminal shows the below:

LF will be replaced by CRLF in app.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

-What is it about?

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicated question. Those are diffents types of [line ending characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). You can get information about the differences on:
[Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

For its relation and importance on git, I think this part of the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings) expresses it very well:

> Every time you press return on your keyboard you insert an invisible
> character called a line ending. Different operating systems handle
> line endings differently.
>
> When you're collaborating on projects with Git and GitHub, Git might
> produce unexpected results if, for example, you're working on a
> Windows machine, and your collaborator has made a change in macOS.
>
> You can configure Git to handle line endings automatically so you can
> collaborate effectively with people who use different operating
> systems.