# fs.readFileSync adds \r to the end of each string

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm using `let names = fs.readFileSync(namefile).toString().split("\n")`. Whenever I do

```
for(const name of names) {
   console.log(`First Name: ${name.split(" ")[0]} Last Name: ${name.split(" ")[1]}
}
```

the last name part always has `\r` at the end, how do I make it not add the `\r`?

Answer (score 8):

**`fs.readFileSync` doesn't add anything to the end of lines,**

instead the file that you're trying to read is using `CRLF` line endings, meaning that each line ends with the `\r\n` sequence.

Really your file looks something like this:

```
line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n
```

But your text editor will hide these characters from you.

---

### There are two different ways you can fix this problem.

1. **Change the type of line endings used in your text editor**

This is IDE specific but if you use Visual Studio Code you can find the option in the bottom right.

[image]

Clicking on it will allow you to change to `LF` line endings, a sequence where lines are followed by a single `\n` character.

2. **Replace unwanted `\r` characters**

Following on from your example we can use `.replace` to remove any `\r` characters.

```js
let names = fs.readFileSync(namefile)
              .toString()
              .replace(/\r/g, "")
              .split("\n")
```

[More on line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552749)