# Error when executing email send code in Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, gmail

I wrote a code to send a confirmation email with Python and it works, but when I put it in the function, sending the code has a problem. Please help me.
code :

```
import smtplib
import random
verify_code=str(random.randint(1111,9999))
sent_from = 'code@r*****'
password='*******'
to = ['re******@gmail.com']
subject = 'verify code'
body = ('your code is :'+str(code))


email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mx2.ta*******.com', 465)
smtp_server.ehlo()
smtp_server.login(sent_from, password)
smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
smtp_server.close()
print ("Email sent successfully!")
```

and When I put in the function :

```
def mail(code):
    import smtplib
    import random
    code=str(random.randint(1111,9999))
    sent_from = 'code@r****'
    password='*******'
    to = ['re*******@gmail.com']
    subject = 'verify code'
    body = ('your code is :'+str(code))


    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)
    
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mx2.tal*****.com', 465)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(sent_from, password)
    smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    smtp_server.close()
    print ("Email sent successfully!")
```

Error while executing the function:

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

reza*****@gmail.com
host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [108.177.126.27]
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
550-5.7.1 [185.51.***.***] Our system has detected that this message is not RFC
550-5.7.1 5322 compliant:
550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing.
550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been
550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant
550 5.7.1  and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Attempt 1 : ratelimit number of emails sent

You are probably sending too many emails at once. Try waiting a few seconds between each email. Since you are using a Gmail account to send emails, you might want to have a look at the [email quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) imposed by Google.

Also if you are calling your function in a loop, you are sending multiple emails to the same recipient. The parameter of your function should the email of the recipient instead of `code`.

```py
import smtplib
import random
import time

def mail(recipient):

    code = str(random.randint(1111, 9999))
    sent_from = 'code@r****'
    password = '*******'
    to = [recipient]
    subject = 'verify code'
    body = ('your code is :'+str(code))
    email_text = """From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s
    
    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mx2.tal*****.com', 465)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(sent_from, password)
    smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    smtp_server.close()
    print("Email sent successfully!")


recipient_list = ['aaa@gmail.com', 'bbb@gmail.com']
for recipient in recipient_list:
    mail(recipient)
    time.sleep(1)  # wait 1s before sending next email
```

#### Attempt 2 : use CRLF character directly in `email_text`

The format of the From field field as [required by RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) is :

> "From:" mailbox-list CRLF

In Python the CRLF character is `\r\n` so lets use it directly in `email_text` as shown below :

```py
    email_text = (
        """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n%s"""
        % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body))
```

This ensures that  the correct [line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types) are inserted at the right place. (we don't have to rely on the line breaks inserted by Enter key)

full code with function :

```py
import smtplib
import random


def mail():
    code = str(random.randint(1111, 9999))
    sent_from = 'code@r****'
    password = '*******'
    to = ['re*******@gmail.com']
    subject = 'verify code'
    body = ('your code is :'+str(code))

    email_text = (
        """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n%s"""
        % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body))

    print(email_text)
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mx2.tal*****.com', 465)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(sent_from, password)
    smtp_server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    smtp_server.close()
    print("Email sent successfully!")


mail()
```

Comment: No, this code of yours didn't work either, I only send the confirmation code to one email and I don't send multiple emails. The code inside the function doesn't work, but without the function it is completely healthy and the code runs easily.

Comment: is the error message for my code same as the error message before?

Comment: Yes, the error is exactly the same

Comment: I fixed an error in the formatting of `email_text`. Can you try again?

Comment: Thank you very much, your second code worked :)