# How to make p5.js count the amount of paragraphs in a txt file

Tags: p5.js

I've been trying to make my p5.js program try to read a text file and notice when it hits a new paragraph, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. for example, right now I'm using 7 paragraphs of just Lorem Ipsum and each paragraph is divided by an entire empty line. how could I make p5.js notice this empty line and count the paragraphs?

i've already tried detecting if there was at least 2 spaces but i'm not sure if I just did it wrong or it doesn't work.

Comment: This is too vague. Please show the text file and your code so far to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find every index of a line break in the text file so you can handle them accordingly.

```
var str = "This is a line.\nThis is another line.\nThis is a third line.";
var indices = [];
for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    if (str[i] === "\n") indices.push(i);
}
```

The indices array holds the indexes of every `\n` character in the string.

**Note:** Be careful of [different line break characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)