# React Native 0.71 Typescript Prettier Error

Tags: typescript, react-native

[image]App is run without any problem but This red warnings disturbing me. How i can solve it?[image]

Comment: It is impossible to say what's causing the errors if you don't also post the error messages.

Comment: i added error messages

Comment: if you are not using typeScript the try to change file extension to .js from .tsx or .ts and restart Code editor

Answer (score 2):

you need to change "select end of line sequence" from CRLF to LF. It is on the bottom tab of Vscode. Here is a good read on StackOverflow

[Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)