# Trimming text/varchar column when duplicates not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a mysql table, like the one above where the column Product

| ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 |
| 2 | text1 \n |
| 3 | text2 |
| 4 | text3 |
| 5 | text4 \n |

My problem is that i'm not very smart - and have introduced ALOT of products to my table with an new-line in the end. With the following query i figured out, that i had 200k+ rows with a new line:

`` SELECT * FROM `my_product_table` WHERE `Product_Name` REGEXP "\n" ``

I'm looking for a way to trim - all "Product_Name" with a newline if another product with that exact name does not exist already - and if it exits already, i just want to remove it.

I figured the easyiest way was to:

1. Trim all rows possible - since it will throw an error if a duplicate exists, so nothing will happen
2. After everything possible is trimmed - delete the rest

Step 2. is should be easy, by just modifying my query above - but my MYSQL knowledge is sadly lacking a little, when i'm trying step 1. Is this the way to do it? and is it even possible?

*EDIT*
I think i was not clear about the new line, i dont know how to write it in tables on stack, but see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG5oD.jpg - thats how the duplicate value with the "new line" looks

Comment: Is there a unique index on product name?

Comment: Yes, the product_name column have a unique index

Answer (score 1):

You can first eliminate the duplicates and then UPDATE the rest

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `Product_Name` varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `Product_Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'text1'),
    (2, 'text1 \n'),
    (3, 'text2'),
    (4, 'text3'),
    (5, 'text4 \n')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE `Product_Name` LIKE '%\n'
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1) t2 
  WHERE t2.`Product_Name` = TRIM(REPLACE(Table1.`Product_Name`,'\n','')));
```

```
UPDATE Table1 SET `Product_Name` = TRIM(REPLACE(`Product_Name`,'\n','')) WHERE `Product_Name` LIKE '%\n'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

| ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 |
| 3 | text2 |
| 4 | text3 |
| 5 | text4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bjFGzWBk)

In case you have also cr lf or cr alone

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `Product_Name` varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `Product_Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'text1'),
    (2, 'text1 \n'),
    (3, 'text2'),
    (4, 'text3'),
    (5, 'text4 \n'),
  (6, 'text1 \r'),
  (7, 'text1 \r\n')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE `Product_Name` LIKE '%\n' OR `Product_Name` LIKE '%\r' OR `Product_Name` LIKE '%\r\n'
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1) t2 
  WHERE t2.`Product_Name` = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Table1.`Product_Name`,'\r\n',''),'\r',''),'\n','')));
```

```
UPDATE Table1 SET `Product_Name` = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`Product_Name`,'\r\n',''),'\r',''),'\n','')) 
  WHERE `Product_Name` LIKE '%\n' OR `Product_Name` LIKE '%\r' OR `Product_Name` LIKE '%\r\n'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

| ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 |
| 3 | text2 |
| 4 | text3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8xRWNDtD)

Comment: i tried your solution but i can not get it to work - i think its because i did not communicate clearly - its not a \n (its an actual new line):  
See this: https://imgur.com/a/1d4WI5z

Comment: images do't help. at the text from ypur database to the sample fiddle, may you don't have \n alone see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552782/5193536 for all possibility and try them also

Comment: Yours worked, i just had to fix the value! thanks!