# Why is this Kotlin Socket connection taking so long? What can I do to optimize it?

Tags: kotlin, sockets, client, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Socket programming and Kotlin. This code does respond but it takes about 8-10 minutes, but the same code in Python takes about 5 seconds.

Where am I wrong, and what can I do to improve it?

I don't think there are any issues on the server side.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import java.io.BufferedReader import java.io.InputStreamReader import java.io.PrintWriter import java.net.Socket import java.text.SimpleDateFormat import java.util.Date import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() { 
    val server = "commdev.grizzy.com" // Custom Server address 
    val port = 3000 // Server port 
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") 
    val soEvent = "[SO|${dateFormat.format(Date())}]"
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            Socket(server, port).use { socket ->
                println("Connected to the server at $server on port $port")
    
                PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true).use { out ->
                    BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).use { `in` ->
                        // Send the SO event to the server
                        out.println(soEvent)
                        println("Sent SO event: $soEvent")
    
                        val responseSO = `in`.readLine()
                        println("Received response to SO event: $responseSO")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try out.flush();. Is it your server? Can you make the server print when it receives a request and sends a response? Which part takes the 8-10 minutes?

Comment: No, it is my company's server. I cannot modify anything. Tried out.flush() hasn't improved the complexity. Output -> Received response to SO event: [RSO|4321|500] in 300102 ms

Comment: Using a tool like Wireshark, do you see any difference between what's sent by your Python implementation and this Kotlin implementation?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the python code so that they can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Is the delay when connecting or when sending the message?  You must know this from when the `Sent SO event...` gets printed.

##### If the delay is when connecting

Is the Kotlin code running on a machine different to the Python code?  If so, it might be due to the IP address of the kotlin machine.  Perhaps the server is trying to do a reverse lookup on the IP (e.g. to get its name) and it is *that* which is introducing the delay.  In any case, I would use `telnet commdev.grizzy.com 3000` on the Kotlin machine and see how long it takes for telnet to connect.

##### If the delay is when sending the mesage

If the server is not responding promptly to the "SO" message you send, then consider how the server knows you have finished sending the "SO..." message.  You are using `out.println(..)` which sends a Line Feed (`LF`) character **only**.  Might the server be expecting `CR` `LF`? ([Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552749/1847378))